# Coded Youtube URL's fullscreen button doesn't work

Tags: url, youtube, fullscreen

I have succesfully coded the following URL to make the youtube video HD:

https://www.youtube.com/v/wnPQC3mAr0k?hl=en_US&version=3&rel=0;&vq=hd720

However, the fullscreen button won't work. Is there any way I could make it work?

Thank you.

-

N.B.: 
I am not speaking about embedded player code.

I am speaking about creating a standalone URL, ie. the one I've written above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set allowFullScreen to 'true'.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not speaking about embedded player code.I am speaking about creating a standalone URL, ie. the one I've written above.